# Is it possible to use Facebook clientId and clientSecret which stored in the database in passport.js Facebook Strategy

Tags: javascript, passport.js

I'm trying to use the Facebook clientId and clientSecret  which stored in the database

this is my code

```
passport.use(
  new FacebookStrategy(
    {
      clientID:
        process.env.AUTH_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID ||
        await getStringConfig('auth', `facebook_client_id`),
      clientSecret:
        process.env.AUTH_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET ||
       await getStringConfig('auth', `facebook_client_secret`),
      callbackURL: WEBSITE_URL + '/api/auth/social/facebook/callback',
      profileFields: ['languages', 'email'],

      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    function (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      socialAuthCallback(
        req as unknown as NextApiRequest,
        'facebook',
        profile,
        done
      )
    }
  )
)
```

`getStringConfig` function returns a promise I know the code is not correct but is there any solution for this problem

when I run the code I got this error

`Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)`

Comment: Which node version you are using?

Comment: The node version is 14.4

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set top level await to true to use it in project. In your webpack config write.

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  experiments: {
    topLevelAwait: true,
  },
};
```